# ros-kinetic-husky-simulator installation failed

Tags: ros, installation, husky, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to install ros-kinetic-husky-simulator by commanding:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-husky-simulator
```

as is said in the tutorial at http://wiki.ros.org/husky_gazebo/Tutorials/Simulating%20Husky .

I get this error

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

and notice a lot of errors like this one

```
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-husky-gazebo/ros-kinetic-husky-gazebo_0.3.1-0xenial-20190131-135412-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
```

If I look at the website, I see that version 0.3.1 is no longer there. It now contains 0.3.3. Therefore I suppose the installation-link that I am using is not working properly. Can anybody help me on how to install the simulator? (I am at beginners-level in Ubuntu.) And also, hopefully we can fix it in the tutorial, as I suppose at this moment everybody who tries to install it has the same problem.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328407/ros-kinetic-husky-simulator-installation-failed/) by [martijn_](https://answers.ros.org/users/44050/martijn_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's likely that you're running into #q325039.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martijn_](https://answers.ros.org/users/44050/martijn_/) on 2019-07-13**:
This solved my problem. Thanks!